Meta data omitted when adding data object to array - Laravel
I have the following function in Laravel :
public static function foo($data)
{
    if (gettype($data) === 'array')
        $data = (object)$data;

    return $data;
}

That prints the following data:
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": "9cdd1234",
        "first_name": "Adam",
        "last_name": "Long",
        "groups": [
            {
                "id": "9cdd1234",
                "name": "1st XV"
            }
        ],
        "status": "PENDING_ASSESSMENT",
        "organisations": [
            "Demo Organisation"
        ],
        "r2s_date": null
    },
    {
        "id": "9cdd1234",
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Murray",
        "groups": [
            {
                "id": "9cdd1234",
                "name": "Test"
            }
        ],
        "status": "PENDING_ASSESSMENT",
        "organisations": [
            "Demo Organisation"
        ],
        "r2s_date": null
    },
     ...
    {
        "id": "9cdd1234",
        "first_name": "Si",
        "last_name": "Poorty",
        "groups": [],
        "status": "CLEARED",
        "organisations": [
            "Demo Organisation"
        ],
        "r2s_date": null
    }
],
"links": {
    "first": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/organisation/9cdd1234/individuals?page=1",
    "last": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/organisation/9cdd1234/individuals?page=1",
    "prev": null,
    "next": null
},
"meta": {
    "current_page": 1,
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 1,
    "links": [
        {
            "url": null,
            "label": "&laquo; Previous",
            "active": false
        },
        {
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/organisation/9cdd1234/individuals?page=1",
            "label": "1",
            "active": true
        },
        {
            "url": null,
            "label": "Next &raquo;",
            "active": false
        }
    ],
    "path": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/organisation/9cdd1234/individuals",
    "per_page": 15,
    "to": 12,
    "total": 12
}

But when I do:
if (gettype($data) === 'array')
        $data = (object)$data;

    $tt = [
        'foo' => $data
    ];

    return $tt;

Then somehow the result is magically being reduced to just the data:
{
    "foo": [
       {
            "id": "9cdd1234",
            "first_name": "Adam",
            "last_name": "Long",
            "groups": [
                {
                    "id": "9cdd1234",
                    "name": "1st XV"
                }
            ],
            "status": "PENDING_ASSESSMENT",
            "organisations": [
                "Demo Organisation"
            ],
            "r2s_date": null
        },
        {
            "id": "9cdd1234",
            "first_name": "John",
            "last_name": "Murray",
            "groups": [
                {
                    "id": "9cdd1234",
                    "name": "Test"
                }
            ],
            "status": "PENDING_ASSESSMENT",
            "organisations": [
                "Demo Organisation"
            ],
            "r2s_date": null
        },
         ...
        {
            "id": "9cdd1234",
            "first_name": "Si",
            "last_name": "Poorty",
            "groups": [],
            "status": "CLEARED",
            "organisations": [
                "Demo Organisation"
            ],
            "r2s_date": null
        }
    ]
}

And the keys: links, meta, etc are being completely omitted. I am busting my head trying to understand why this is happening and I am going nowhere. I'd love to understand this behaviour so if anyone can shed some light to this I'd be grateful.

likely you are passing in the foo method only the data part of your input

@krisgjika - nope, I pass in the whole thing! That's what blows my mind!
